# AWS Step Functions TaskTimedOut

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am using boto3 in my activity workers and I came upon a TaskTimedOut when calling the SendTaskFailure:

```
botocore.errorfactory.TaskTimedOut: An error occurred (TaskTimedOut) when calling the SendTaskFailure operation: Task Timed Out: 'arn:aws:states:eu-west-2:statemachinearn:activityname'
```

I think this happens because the connection pool gets full sometimes which makes the request not being fulfilled (even though a new connection is created).

I know it is possible to set a timeout value for Tasks and Parallel States but that does not have anything to do with calling the send_task_failure/send_task_success methods.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can explain one scenario which I encountered in step function.
I was using nested state machines and in my main state machine, I used to get exception like 'timeout when invoking state machine', one in 1000s. As it was transient error, i had to handle it as per specs provided by AWS so I explicitly added retry for framework exceptions like below.

```
"Retry": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "StepFunctions.SdkClientException"
      ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 10,
      "MaxAttempts": 4,
      "BackoffRate": 2
    }
  ]
```